# Export Grid to Word doc using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

i have been trying export grid view to doc . and facing issues .

List of data contains data from database in from of List<>.

```
GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = ListofData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
      Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export-Grid.doc");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

problem with this approach is

1) when i open Export-Grid.doc in Office 2013 it prompts me that u want to open file as HTml Document , PDF document etc . if i try to open document using HTML it writes all data in file but in html form and if i use Plain text option it do same thing writes html data.

2) if i try to open Export-Grid.doc using open office it open the document but columns width is to big

i m using asp.net mvc. can some one help me how can i fix this or let me know wat m doing wrong ??? 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/375965/How-to-convert-GridView-data-to-Excel-PDF-Word-fil use this link and let me if this link is good for you or not

Comment: i have seen this link. there is not much difference in his or my code but it doesn't solve my prb :S